# IBM Mobilefirst 8 - Cordova app crashed when add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, crosswalk

i'm using Ionic 3 and crosswalk webview on my Mobilefirst 8 project, but application crashes on launching and give errors below:

```
08-16 09:51:22.246 17767-17767/com.package E/chromium: [ERROR:xwalk_platform_notification_service.cc(143)] Not implemented reached in virtual bool xwalk::XWalkPlatformNotificationService::GetDisplayedPersistentNotifications(content::BrowserContext*, std::__1::set<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >*)
08-16 09:51:22.258 17767-17767/com.package E/chromium: [ERROR:xwalk_browser_context.cc(88)] Failed to read preference, error num: 0
08-16 09:51:22.447 369-369/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for service=batteryproperties scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:healthd_service:s0 tclass=service_manager
08-16 09:51:22.694 17767-17831/com.package E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
08-16 09:51:22.772 2571-2595/? E/MP-Decision: Update arg 1
08-16 09:51:24.599 17767-17823/com.package E/v8: #
                                                                   # Fatal error in , line 0
                                                                   # 
08-16 09:51:24.599 17767-17823/com.package E/v8: Failed to create ICU number format, are ICU data files missing?
08-16 09:51:24.599 17767-17823/com.package E/v8: #
```

Cordova version: 7.0.1.
Ionic version: 3.6.0.

Here is my cordova plugins list:

```
com.googlemaps.ios 2.2.0-fixed "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 0.0.2 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.7 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.0 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"
cordova-plugin-http 1.2.0 "SSL Pinning"
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017072706 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2017062111 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - Push Notifications"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.1.4-dev "Cordova WKWebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: What is your android version?

Comment: Is this specific to a version of Android ?

Comment: The Android version using to test is 6.0

Comment: Hi, any news?! Thx you